# Question about neighborhood of a set and the validity of my example

Tags: general-topology

There is a statement about neighborhood of a set :

> A subset $V$ of a topological space $X$ is a neighborhood of the set $S$ if and only if $V$ is a neighborhood for each point in $S$, in other words if there exist an open subset $U$ of $V$ such that it contains $S$.

I tried to convince myself using an example:

Let $V$ be a neighborhood for every $x$ in $S$, based on the definition of neighborhood of a point we have that there exist $U_x⊆X$ such that $x∈U_x⊆V$

Now let the real line be the topological space and $V=\left(-2,2\right)$ , $S=\left(-1,1\right)$ ,$U=\left(-1.5,1.5\right)$ and $U_x=\left(-0.1+x,x+0.1\right)$

Here for every $x$ in $S$ we have $x∈\left(-1.5,1.5\right)⊆\left(-2,2\right)$, so the union of these $x$'s is a subset of the union of all such $U_x$'s , in other words:

$$S = \bigcup_{x \in S} x⊆\bigcup_{x \in S}U_x⊆V$$

equivalently
$$\left(-1,1\right) = \bigcup_{x \in \left(-1,1\right)} x⊆\bigcup_{x  \in \left(-1,1\right)}\left(-0.1+x,x+0.1\right)⊆\left(-2,2\right)$$

Hence the set $V=\left(-2,2\right)$ is a neighborhood for the set $S=\left(-1,1\right)$, as desired.

Here we don't have the equility $U = \bigcup_{x \in S} U_x$, since $$\left(-1.5,1.5\right)\ne\left(-0.1+x,x+0.1\right)$$

But the result still follows.

My question is that am I right in the example ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two equivalent definitions of neighborhood of a set here, separated by the phrase "in other words", and you seem to be mixing them.  They are

> A subset $V$ of a topological space $X$ is a neighborhood of the set $S$ if and only if $V$ is a neighborhood for each point in $S$.

and

> A subset $V$ of a topological space $X$ is a neighborhood of the set $S$ if and only if there exists an open subset $U$ of $V$ such that it contains $S$.

It is sufficient to show either, but there is no reason to attempt to relate your $U_x$s for the first with the $U$ of the second.

Comment: yes you are right, I'm just saying even without having the equality $U = \bigcup_{x \in S} U_x$  the result still follows (The result that the set $V$ is a neighborhood for the set $S$)

Comment: @user715522 : If you are working in the first definition, then to show the second, you require that whatever $\bigcup_{x \in S} U_x$ is, it is an open subset of $V$ such that it contains $S$.  You do not require that it is some previously specified open subset of $V$ such that it contains $S$.  If you are working in the second definition, then to show the first, you show that each $x \in S$ has an open neighborhood contained in, $U_x \subseteq S$.  You do not require that the union of of the $U_x$ happens to be some previously specified open subset of $V$ containing $S$.

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct (you could add the statement that the union of the open subsets $U_x$ is again open). The fact that $U\neq\bigcup_{x\in S}U_x$ is indeed no problem since you could easily choose a different form for $U_x$ such that it would be the case.